# Plotly stacked bar chart add_trace loop issue

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a stacked bar chart in plotly and whenever I run my loop for add_trace, there is an issue as data of the previous trace seems to dissapear while names remain.

```
        p = plot_ly( x = rownames(dist_data), y = as.numeric(dist_data[,1]), type = 'bar', name = colnames(dist_data)[1])%>%
      layout(legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9))

    for ( j in 2:length(colnames(dist_data)))
    {
      p =  add_trace(p, y = ~as.numeric(dist_data[,j]), type = 'bar',name = colnames(dist_data)[j]) %>%
        layout( barmode = 'stack')
    }
    p
```

I am wondering whether there is something wrong in the loop.
When trying manually for adding trace1, works fine. When adding trace 2 (j=3), trace1's values become automatically equal to trace2's value.

**UPD:** When using dplyr, I have issues with some other parts of my code.
Is there a solution without it?

Thank you for the help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting p at each loop iteration. Try:

```
p =  p %>% add_trace(y = ~as.numeric(dist_data[,j]), type = 'bar',name = colnames(dist_data)[j]) %>%
        layout( barmode = 'stack')
```

2nd Edit:
not sure why this is happening. It works if you reshape to a long format dataframe which is better practice than using a for loop:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(id = rownames(.)) %>%
  gather(key = "variable",value = "value",-id) %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~id, y=~value, type="bar", color=~variable) %>%
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

[image]

Edit:

```
dist_data=mtcars
p = plot_ly( x = rownames(dist_data), 
             y = as.numeric(dist_data[,1]), 
             type = 'bar', name = colnames(dist_data)[1]) %>%
  layout(legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9))

for ( j in 2:length(colnames(dist_data))){
  p =  add_trace(p, y = ~as.numeric(dist_data[,j]), 
type = 'bar',name = colnames(dist_data)[j]) %>%
    layout( barmode = 'stack')
}
p
```

Comment: I am getting same results.

Comment: And it wasn't overwriting because I could see on my plot all 7 data labels from name = colnames(dist_data)[j]

Comment: you are right, it's the same result. The plot is good for me with dist_data = mtcars though. Maybe a pb with you dataframe?

Comment: Well look at the values. All values starting second variable are the same, as example all maseratti bora are at 8.

Comment: Finally it works:) still quite a challenge. Would you help me with a last thing? 
The dist_data contains dates as rownames, how could I have the x axis as a date? Converting to xts isn't a solution here I believe

Comment: :) use `as.Date()` function
`as.Date(rownames(dist_data))` and specify a format argument if your date format is ambiguous

Comment: When using dplyr, I have issues with some other parts of my code.
Is there a solution without it?

Comment: Might have overwritten some functions.
You can avoid loading dplyr and just add `dplyr::` in front of mutate and `tidyr::` in front if `gather`. The rest of your code should not be affected anymore